# NSXMLElements breaking line before close TAG - Cocoascript

Tags: xml, plugins, sketch-3, export-to-xml, cocoascript

I'm creating an XML file. What I need is to have a line-break before close the TAG
My expected printout is

```xml
<View 
    x=“0” y=“0" 
    width=“464” height=“287">
</View>
```

instead, the output I have is the following:

```
<View 
    x=“0” y=“0" 
    width=“464” height=“287"></View>
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
var layerElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"View"];
[layerElement addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"\n \tx" stringValue:layerXpos]];
[layerElement addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"y" stringValue:layerYpos]];
[layerElement addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"\n \twidth" stringValue:layerWidth]];
[layerElement addAttribute:[NSXMLNode attributeWithName:@"height" stringValue:layerHeight]];
[root addChild:layerElement];
```

In the doc page, I found only some reference for compact/expand the empty tags ( [NSXMLNodeOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlnodeoptions?language=objc)), but nothing to format the TAG when it's not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, simpler than expected:

```js
var layerElement = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"View" stringValue:"\n"];
```

Just adding the new line (`@"\n"`) attribute to a `stringValue` parameter everything will work fine.

If anyone else knows something that will work better, please add your answer.